# (XMBC) Reversed buttons 4 and 5 not working as they should

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, mouse, xmouse

XMBC Version: v2.17

Windows Version: Win7

Mouse Information (brand/model): Zelotes T-80

A clear description of the problem: My mouse comes with inverted backwards and forwards buttons. I have no idea why, but I don't have any other solutions, except for key mapping.

But there is a problem with some of the applications. Chrome works fine with reversed buttons, but Discord doesn't. Discord detects as though both buttons were pressed simultaneously. It's annoying, so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or does discord grab input directly from mouse and windows, so it gets both.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely just a button assignment issue. Open the program you use to control your mouse buttons and re-assign them to the correct positions.

Comment: I checked them, also stopped XMBC, but to no avail.If I disable XMBC, I just get the reversed thumb buttons, If I swap them, it works in Chrome, but not discord, discord detects both of them...